# kubectl minikube renew certificate

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm using `kubectl` to access the api server on my minikube cluster on ubuntu
but when try to use `kubectl` command I got an error certificate expired:

```
/home/ayoub# kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2021-08-30T14:39:50+01:00 is before 2021-08-30T14:20:10Z
```

Here's my kubectl config:

```
/home/ayoub# kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:16443
  name: microk8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: microk8s-cluster
    user: admin
  name: microk8s
current-context: microk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    token: REDACTED
root@ayoub-Lenovo-ideapad-720S-13IKB:/home/ayoub#    /home/ayoub# kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:16443
  name: microk8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: microk8s-cluster
    user: admin
  name: microk8s
current-context: microk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    token: REDACTED
root@ayoub-Lenovo-ideapad-720S-13IKB:/home/ayoub#
```

How I can renew this certificate?

Comment: there is one open issue with minikube https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10122

Answer (score 3):

minikube delete - deletes the local Kubernetes cluster - worked for me

reference:
 **https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10122#issuecomment-758227950**

Answer (score 2):

Posted community wiki for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

There is similar issue opened on [minikube GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10122).

The temporary workaround is to remove some files in the `/var/lib/minikube/` directory, then reset Kubernetes cluster and replace keys on the host. Those steps are described in [this answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10122#issuecomment-888315632).

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in this blog solved the problem for me:

https://dev.to/boris/microk8s-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-x509-certificate-has-expired-or-is-not-yet-valid-2b73

In summary:

Run `sudo microk8s.refresh-certs` then restarting the servers to reboot the microk8s cluster

Comment: ` sudo microk8s.refresh-certs --cert ca.crt` solves the issues for me for one day. But it needs to be done every morning it seems. Would you know the root cause? I looked at the ` /snap/microk8s/current/certs-beta/ca.crt` file I found in microk8s and its validies are ok

Comment: I just realise that the refresh-certs command didn't update the ca.crt file I mentioned. What did it update then? I don't understand...

Comment: Topic explicitly mentions minikube